# How to convert column values to multiple rows for a csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
check_NUMBER,2021-12-01,2022-01-01,2022-02-01
1000M,24,17,22
1000M,24,83,55
```

This is my example data. I want to convert it into:

```
check_NUMBER,dates,values
1000M,2021-12-01,24
1000M,2021-12-01,17
1000M,2021-12-01,22
1000M,2022-02-01,24
1000M,2022-02-01,83
1000M,2022-02-01,55
```

I am unable to achieve this. Can someone explain how we can do that.

Comment: have you tried making a new data frame and parsing the old one into it with the desired structure?

Comment: I think you can use melt. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt

Comment: I am not that good in python, I read the doc. But I wasn't very sure how to proceed.

Comment: I'm baffled by what you're trying to achieve, why are you associating 17 and 22 with  2021-12-01 ? And 24, 83 with 2022-02-01 ? I fail to see the logic. Using `df.melt` makes sense when I look at the original dataframe, but it doesn't produce what you want to convert it into.

Answer (score 2):

Use [df.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

**Code**

```
df.melt(id_vars='check_NUMBER', var_name='dates', value_name='values')
```

**Output**

```
check_NUMBER    dates   values
0   1000M   2021-12-01  24
1   1000M   2021-12-01  24
2   1000M   2022-01-01  17
3   1000M   2022-01-01  83
4   1000M   2022-02-01  22
5   1000M   2022-02-01  55
```